# IDEA 2016.1, Gradle's processResources expanding not working automatically

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have an IDEA 2016.1 Enterprise and a Gradle 2.12 multi-module project. In one of the modules, in src/main/resources, I have a file which I would like Gradle to 'expand', here is my configuration:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('my.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

(I would like to expand just this single file, and just copy the rest.)

It all works fine when built on the command line, but not by default in IDEA - when I clean and build the project, the file lands in `build/resources/main` but the placeholders are not replaced. I have to manually invoke the Gradle `processResources` task using the Gradle pane in IDEA and double clicking on the task.

Is this something I should report to Jetbrains (i.e. a bug) or has anybody have it working and I should change something in my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

When you build from command line, you are using gradle. However, when you build the project from intellij, by default intellij doesn't use gradle to build, but use its internal build system which doesn't understand your gradle's `processResources`.

One way to solve it is to check "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" as shown below:

[image: delegate build to gradle]

If you don't want to use gradle build in intellij, there's another workaround - add `processResources` as a gradle task to run after `build` in your "Run/Debug Configurations":

[image: add processResources task after build]

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the dependency in your `build.gradle` file, eg.

```
assemble.dependsOn processResources
```

This should work if you have `java` plugin applied.

Comment: Thanks. According to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html (Figure 45.1), assemble depends on jar, which depends on classes, which depends on processResources, so assemble already indirectly depends on processResources. I tried it anyways and it didn't work.

Comment: This also didn't change anything for me. I am facing the same issue @wujek, did you solve your problem?